# What gets returned return type is reference of object?

Tags: c++, oop, object, reference, destructor

This is what i believe:

When a function returns it make a new temporary copy of the object and this temp object remains in memory for the time of the statement from where it was called.

when a function returns reference that object is itself returned. This means that that object should not be local.

so when i do this:

```
 MyStruct & ReferenceReturn(MyStruct cl)
 {
         return cl;
 }
```

in main() i do

```
MyStruct d("notmyname"),g("myname");
d = ReferenceReturn(g);
cout << d.name;
cout << ReferenceReturn(g).name;
```

It prints garbage in both.

What gets returned ? : reference to local copy of g i.e. cl which gets destroyed as soon as function is finished or a reference to temporary object that gets destroyed after the statement is over. But since if temp would have been created it would have overritten d in the right way. So i believe that it is the reference of localcopy of passed value that is getting returned .

But as soon as i made destructor in the struct it went perfectly, with following code and specific output.

```
 ~MyStruct()
 {
   cout << name << " is destroying";
  }
```

Output:

```
myname is destroying
myname
myname
myname is destroying
....
```

This output shows that only one object is created for each call. (there are two calls)

But why it is not working without destructor ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the result undefined for such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 MyStruct & ReferenceReturn(MyStruct cl)
 {
         return cl;
 }
```

Create `temporary object`, assign it to `cl`, return `reference` to object, destruct object. So, it's `dangling reference`. Compiler can use `copy-elision` and don't copy object, but can not... Use something lile

```
 MyStruct & ReferenceReturn(MyStruct& cl)
 {
         return cl;
 }
```

Comment: I found that  object is getting destructed after the statement. when i added the destructor, it output is coming after             cout << ReferenceResult(g) << endl; so that object is getting destructed after this line is done.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI How about insert trace in copy-ctor? http://liveworkspace.org/code/8077039f76b8b4a52d09977b94f31155 but in MSVC results are not same. So, such usage is incorrect by standard.

Comment: As you can see, the passed object's destructor ouput "d-tor" is called after the statement "cout " which prints "0" , this means that object is good before that statement is finished. So its working .. but when i removed destructor and copy constructor ; garbage gets printed in my case.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI it's incorrect by standard. Realisation of this case in complilers is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
 MyStruct & ReferenceReturn(MyStruct cl) {
    return cl;
 }
```

> Is the result undefined for such cases?

That function exhibits undefined behavior, yes. The problem is that `cl` is a local object in the function, and you are returning a reference to it. This is undefined behavior. The caller will create a copy of `g` to be passed to `ReferenceReturn`, and that copy will be destroyed by the `ReferenceReturn` function after the `return`, potentially before the caller gets to use the reference.

Comment: "Potentially before the caller gets to use the reference" Without destructor you are right; When i right destuctor something else happens--> local copy of function is getting destroyed after the cout statement. So destructor doing somehing here or it is undefined as you said.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI: I am not sure how I can make it clearer: the function exhibits undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that it can seem to work or it might provide incorrect results or crash the application, but it is still undefined behavior in all cases.